# How to center align watermark when using burning image plugin in Grails

Tags: grails

I need to apply watermarks to the uploaded images. According to the documentation for the burning image this is done with following code:

```
def orginalFileName      
burningImageService.doWith('path/to/my/file.jpg', 'path/to/output/dir')
    .execute {
        it.scaleApproximate(800, 600)
        orginalFileName = it.watermark('path/to/watermark',
                                       ['right':10, 'bottom': 10])
    }
    .execute ('thumbnail', {
        it.scaleAccurate(200, 200)
    })
```

Is there an easy way to center align the watermark without needing to calculate the coordinates? I cannot use the given size (800,600) since it is an approximate size. I cannot use scaleAccurate because I don't want to crop the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the position coordinate from the parameters and it will center the watermark by default.

```
burningImageService.doWith('path/to/my/file', 'path/to/output/dir')
                   .execute {
                       it.watermark('path/to/watermark')
                    }
```

For more info please refer:
https://code.google.com/p/burningimage/wiki/Images_manipulation_handling